# Regular expression of ' and "

Tags: sql, regex, apostrophe

what is the regular expression to not allow enter ' and '' ?

because when the user enter the text with ' Example : i'm Mr Right -> it cause a error on SQL 2008.

i know, that i have 2 choice:

1. not allow user to enter ' and "" (with regex)
2. i will replace all the ' with \' and " with \" (i don't know if it work)

solution with regex:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox runat="server" EnableClientSideAPI="True" Width="160px" ID="Info"
                            ClientInstanceName="Email">
                            <ValidationSettings SetFocusOnError="True">
                                <RegularExpression ErrorText="Invalid e-mail" ValidationExpression="" />
                                <RequiredField IsRequired="True" ErrorText="E-mail is required" />
                            </ValidationSettings>
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

solution with replace:

```
Info.Replace("'", "\'");
```

Thanks you in advance,
Stev

Comment: What kind of input is this? A long text, username, etc?

Comment: you can replace `'`with `''` fro sql

Comment: You should always go with your second method. This is known as character escaping.

Comment: How are you entering those fields in the database? You're not concatenating the string the user entered to build an SQL insert statement are you? You shouldn't need to escape those characters if you're using parameters. As an aside, you _do_ know that both single and double quotes are legal in email addresses? (Yes they're pretty uncommon, and some email services don't allow it at all, [but still](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax)...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is `^[^'"]*$` which will accept anything but those two characters.

To write this in C# use:

```
@"^[^'""]*$"
```

If you plan to insert the address into the DB you will probably need to remove or escape additional characters. Actually you should use something that does this automatically such as linq-to-sql or entity-framework.

Comment: LINQ-to-SQL is a good suggestion, but AIUI it works by generating templated SQL statements, which allows it to avoid quoting “fun” completely. That's both faster and safer…

Comment: @DonalFellows YOu don't need an ORM, just parametrised `DbCommand`s. (No string concatenation to build the SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the user to enter a text, then write a simple regular expression that will not allow the user to enter single quotes or double quotes..

```
        Regex valid = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]+$");           
        if (valid.IsMatch(TextBox.Text))
        {
         // write code here...
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error","Error");
        }
```

You will not need to write special regular expression : Regex valid = new Regex(@"^[']*$");